# Extract entity using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

***What I have:***
*"peak hour traffic at **location1** towards **location2**, **location3** towards **location4** and **location5** towards **location6**."*

example:
*"peak hour traffic at ulsoor lake jn towards nagatheatre jn, okalipuram towards majestic and bamboo bazaar jn towards cole's park jn."*

***What I want:***
extract **locations** using regex in python.

example:

***[('ulsoor lake jn', 'nagatheatre jn'), ('okalipuram', 'majestic'),       ('bamboo bazaar jn', "cole's park jn")]***

*what I have done:*

```
>>> regex1 = '(?:\sat\s|,|and)(.*) towards (.*)(?:\.|,|and)'
>>> re.search(regex1, "peak hour traffic at ulsoor lake jn towards nagatheatre jn, okalipuram towards majestic and bamboo bazaar jn towards cole's park jn.").groups()
15: ('ulsoor lake jn towards nagatheatre jn, okalipuram towards majestic and bamboo bazaar jn',
"cole's park jn")
```

**What I am getting**:

***('ulsoor lake jn towards nagatheatre jn, okalipuram towards majestic and bamboo bazaar jn',
    "cole's park jn")***

*As it can be seen it's only matching the external expression when there are sub-expression that matches the pattern. Please help. Thank You.*

Comment: Change your `(.*)`'s for the capture to `(.*?)` so it doesn't consume your next boundary?

Comment: @g.d.d.c can you please explain how it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need a couple of things.  First - like my comment said - use `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)` so that your captures are not greedy.

Second - use a look-ahead assertion so you don't advance the parser when determing where a capture ends,

Third - use `findall` instead of `search`.

```
>>> r = re.compile('(?:\sat\s|,|and)(.*?) towards (.*?)(?=\.|,|and)')
>>> s = "peak hour traffic at ulsoor lake jn towards nagatheatre jn, okalipuram towards majestic and bamboo bazaar jn to wards cole's park jn."
>>>
>>> r.findall(s)
[('ulsoor lake jn', 'nagatheatre jn'), (' okalipuram', 'majestic '), (' bamboo bazaar jn', "cole's park jn")]
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how `(.*?)` this works instead of `(.*)` or any reference.

Comment: There are tons of references on regex, including this one:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.  The section on Conditionals covers the `?`: http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html.

Comment: Short answer: if you look for `b.*a` in your regex, the `.*` is *greedy* - that is, it matches as many characters as possible. So a string "b1a2a3a" would match "b1a2a3a" because "as many as possible. But if you tell the pattern to be "non-greedy" it will match as many characters as necessary - the minimum work to satisfy the pattern. "b1a2a3a" would just match "b1a" and stop.